# How to fix the datagridview display of the application in C# that is run in different OS?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm confused on how to fix the datagridview display in my C# application. I developed the application in W10, but when I tried running the application in W7. The display is different compared to W10.

First datagridview

[W7 display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaYFi.jpg)

[W10 display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lggx.jpg) (same datagridview as above)

[W7 display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLvmU.jpg)

[W10 display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBAQK.jpg) (same datagridview as above)

The datagridview display correctly but,

Other datagridviews

[W7 display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH5KN.jpg)

[W10 display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aC9q.jpg) (same datagridview as above)

In this datagridview display, it doesn't show 6 columns. The user needs to adjust the columns size and the splitcontainer, to show the other columns.

Also in this datagridview

[W7 display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJlhi.jpg)

[W10 display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLI3Q.jpg) (same datagridview as above)

There are some columns that are not shown, or it goes over the margin.

Datagridview properties

- All datagridviews are `Anchor` in Top,Bottom,Left,Right
- `AutoSizeColumnMode` is set to `Fill`
- `ColumnHeaderHeightSizeMode` is set to `AutoSize`
- The data is populated by a database

Comment: So... you are asking how to make a 2001 technology look like a 2016 one? Not really doable, is it?

Comment: Hmm. So no work around?

Comment: Can you explain to me. Why on the first datagridview it display correctly even if I resize the form window?

Comment: Nevermind. I have solved the issue using `TableLayoutPanel` and `Dock` properties. Now it is showing how I want it to be. :D

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you are creating the datagridviews manually. But if not, I would copy one of the datagridview that is working fine and replace it by the one that is not working. Then change the datagridview source by the one you need and see if it works. This is something I have applied multiple times when I'm facing problems like these. Hope this suggestion helps you out.

Comment: I have already done that. But still not all the columns are visible, or somehow go over outside the `DataGridView` size. I'm not sure if the `SplitContainer` inside the `TabPage` is causing the problem. Only that `TabPage` is causing this problem, other `TabPage` with `DataGridView` as well, doesn't show this kind of problem. By the way, solved the issue using `TableLayoutPanel` and `Dock` properties.